# Resizing iframes that have an iframe in them that resizes

Tags: iframe

Alright. I want to try and explain this as best I can.

I am working on a website that has a webpage with an iframe on it.
The iframe shows another webpage that has it's own iframe in it.

The iframe in the iframe changes size, particularly the height.

How do I get both the iframe in the iframe and the iframe displaying the iframe...(Oye, confusing) to change height together?

Basically what I have is a webpage that has an iframe in an iframe and that iframe in the iframe is a forum page. Which means that as people post to it the inner iframe changes height and thus needs to expand the iframe it is contained in.

Man just asking this question really confuses me.

I've scored google and various websites but I can't seem to get a code that does what I am wanting or works for that matter.

Thanks

Comment: Are all the pages of (1) your page, (2) parent `IFRAME`, and (3) child `IFRAME` in the same host name?

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this library to do this you would need to set the middle page to run both the host and iframe scripts and the the size should bubble up to you top level.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but thought I would share my experience. I had pretty much the same issue working on a project at work.  I searched everywhere and tried a lot of different things but finally found this to work pretty well (with the help of a number of posts on here!) .  I tested with FF 30, IE11, and chrome so far. In short, I have a parent HTML page which I was able to put an iframe.  That iframe loads an aspx page that contains another iframe.  That inner most iframe(child_page_2.aspx) had dynamic content in which I wanted both iframes to resize accordingly. Also, just to be clear these are all on the same domain/hostname.

I have paging using a datalist on the inner most iframe(child_page_2.aspx).  Each click of a page number is generating dynamic content of varying heights i.e. going through the paged data. I found that doing an OnClick() event server side and using ScriptManager to fire the clientside javascript would then return me the correct height after the content was loaded. I didn't show all of the DataList code just one of the link buttons nested inside the ItemTemplate.

I know this is pretty much an awful way of setting up a webpage its just what we were forced to do because we only had access to the HTML parent page. The reason for the nested iframes was to give us a sort of "menu" page with content in an iframe below it (child_page_1.aspx --> child_page_2.aspx).

Hope this helps someone!

Parent Page.HTML:

```
<iframe src=child_page_1.aspx id="mainFrame" />
```

child_page_1.aspx:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function adjustMyFrameHeight() {
          var frame = getElement("mainFrame");    
           frame.height = document.body.offsetHeight + 60 + "px";
    }
    function getElement(aID) {
        return (document.getElementById) ?
        parent.document.getElementById(aID) : parent.document.all[aID];
    }

    function updateframeheight(newheight) {
        var frame = document.getElementById("subFrame");
        frame.height = newheight + "px";
        adjustMyFrameHeight();

    }
</head>

<body onload="adjustMyFrameHeight();">

<iframe id="subFrame" src="child_page_2.aspx" >

</body>
```

child_page_2.aspx:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function adjustMyFrameHeight() {
           var frame = getElement("subFrame");
           frame.height = document.body.offsetHeight + 60 + "px";


    }
    function getElement(aID) {
        return (document.getElementById) ?
        parent.document.getElementById(aID) : parent.document.all[aID];

    }
    function updatesize() {
        parent.updateframeheight(document.body.offsetHeight + 60);

    }
</script>
</head>

<body  onload="adjustMyFrameHeight();">
<form>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPrevious" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnPrevious_Click">Previous</asp:LinkButton>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```

child_page_2.aspx.cs:

```
protected void lnkbtnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "updatesize", "updatesize();", true);
    }
```